# Passing api value to formcontrolname

Tags: angular, angular12

I'd like to get certain values from the API and pass them to the formcontrolname. The value of the API doesn't show in the field.

This is how I'm passing the data in the template.

```js
<div *ngFor="let item of events">
    <div *ngFor="let x of item">
        <form action="" [formGroup]="SignupForm" (ngSubmit)="cancelBooking()">
            <div class="pageTitle SystemPageTitle text-center mt-5 schedule_heading">
               Slot : {{x.event_id}}
            </div>
            <div class="container mb-5 mt-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="person_id" value="{{x.person_id}}"><br>
                        <input type="text" formControlName="event_id" value="{{x.event_id}}">

                    </div>
                    <div class="" data-editablearea="0" data-areaheight="auto">
                        <p align="center"><button (click)="cancelBooking()" class="button buttonCancel">Delete</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:
I've added the setValue() function so that I pass the API data from the backend.
My .ts file is as follows.

```
export class BookedEventComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any;
  SignupForm: any;
  x: any;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cancelForm();

    this.authService.getEvents().subscribe(response => {
      this.events = response;
      console.log(response);
    })
  }

  private cancelForm() {
    this.SignupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      person_id: new FormControl(null),
      event_id: new FormControl(null),
    });
  }

  setValue() {
    this.SignupForm.setValue({
      person_id: this.x.person_id,
      event_id: this.x.event_id
    });
  }

  cancelBooking() {
    console.log(this.SignupForm.value);
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete delete")) {
      this.authService.cancelSlot(this.SignupForm.value).subscribe(response => {
        window.location.reload();
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/schedule']);
        }, 1000);
      })
    }
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You should include the `.ts` file code as well. As a remark, your inputs are `type="hidden"`, maybe that's why you can't see the values.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question. The problem still persists though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the value by [`setValue()`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value)

```js
export class SimpleFormGroup {
      
  // data you get from API
  x;

  form = new FormGroup({
    person_id: new FormControl(null),
    event_id: new FormControl(null),
  });

  // Call this when you get data from API
  setValue() {
    this.form.setValue({
       person_id: x.person_id, 
       event_id: x.event_id
    });
  }
}
```

You also find out more at https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName

Comment: Hi, could you please check my edited question.

Comment: @BjornLiza well, you make a loop outside of form, so you should find out more about `FormArray`, in your case, you need to wrap the form with a `FormArrayName`.  That's a lot of effort and I can't do it here. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName